# View is on top left on smaller devices Swift 3, xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-simulator

When i run my app on a 6-7 plus its perfect but on smaller devices this happens [image]

Is there a reason this does this? please let me know! thanks :)

Comment: Check your image format and version! It's must be support all of the device requirements. For example: image@2x, image@3x. Or you've not implemented auto layout properly

Comment: How are you setting up your constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I would say you haven't gotten your constraints correctly yet you may wanna inspect them better it looks like you have them set to the top left corner. You wanna make sure that all the little red I handles are clicked for the sections you want to auto layout

[image]

This section will let you change the device you are viewing it on in the interface builder[image]